# pythonのエラーを解決したいです．ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, python2

公開されていたpythonのコード(出典元：TransE[NIPS'13]を実装(と実験再現)した　URL: http://yamaguchiyuto.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/02/25/080356 )を実行しようとしたところエラーが出てしまいました．pythonに．関して自身がよく分かっていないことが一番の問題なのですが，よろしければ解決をお願いしたいです．

以下がエラーです．

```
(py27) D:\Desktop\pi>python train.py FB15k/freebase_mtr100_mte100-train.txt FB15k/freebase_mtr100_mte100-valid.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 54, in <module>
    transe.fit(X,nepochs=nepochs,validationset=V)
  File "D:\Desktop\pi\transe.py", line 101, in fit
    if not validationset == None: print (i,self.meanrank(validationset))
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

次にエラーが出ていると思われるコードの全てです．

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize

class TRANSE:
    def __init__(self,n,m,r,k,lamb,b,d):
        self.n = n # no. of entities
        self.m = m # no. of relationships
        self.r = r # margin
        self.k = k # no. of dimensions
        self.lamb = lamb # learning rate
        self.b = b # size of minibatch
        self.d = d # distance measure ('l1' or 'l2')

    def meanrank(self,V,nsamples=1000):
        ret = 0.
        k = 0
        for h,r,t in V:
            dsim = self.predict(h,r)
            ret += (dsim<dsim[t]).sum()
            k += 1
            if k >= nsamples: break
        return ret/k

    def get_batches(self,S,b):
        for i in range(S.shape[0]/b-1):
            yield S[i*b:(i+1)*b]
        yield S[(S.shape[0]/b-1)*b:]

    def negative_sampling(self,batch):
        r = np.random.randint(2, size=batch.shape[0])
        e = np.random.randint(self.n, size=batch.shape[0])
        return np.vstack([batch.T,r,e]).T

    def evaluate_grad(self,batch):
        grad = {}
        grad['e'] = np.zeros((self.n,self.k))
        grad['l'] = np.zeros((self.m,self.k))
        count = {}
        count['e'] = np.zeros(self.n)
        count['l'] = np.zeros(self.m)

        T = self.negative_sampling(batch) # unif
        for h,r,t,rnd,e in T:
            if rnd == 1: h2 = h; t2 = e
            else: h2 = e; t2 = t
            if self.f(h,r,t) + self.r - self.f(h2,r,t2) > 0:
                g1 = self.grad_f(h,r,t)
                g2 = self.grad_f(h2,r,t2)
                grad['e'][h] += g1
                grad['e'][t] += -g1
                grad['e'][h2] += -g2
                grad['e'][t2] += g2
                grad['l'][r] += g1-g2
                count['e'][h] += 1
                count['e'][t] += 1
                count['e'][h2] += 1
                count['e'][t2] += 1
                count['l'][r] += 1
        count['e'][count['e']==0] = 1 # avoid division by zero
        count['l'][count['l']==0] = 1 # avoid division by zero
        grad['e'] = (grad['e'].T/count['e']).T # 1/n
        grad['l'] = (grad['l'].T/count['l']).T # 1/n
        return grad

    def grad_f(self,h,r,t):
        if self.d == 'l1':
            return (self.params['e'][h]+self.params['l'][r]-self.params['e'][t])/np.abs(self.params['e'][h]+self.params['l'][r]-self.params['e'][t])
        elif self.d == 'l2':
            return (self.params['e'][h]+self.params['l'][r]-self.params['e'][t])/np.linalg.norm(self.params['e'][h]+self.params['l'][r]-self.params['e'][t])

    def f(self,h,r,t):
        if self.d == 'l1':
            return np.abs(self.params['e'][h]+self.params['l'][r]-self.params['e'][t]).sum()
        elif self.d == 'l2':
            return np.linalg.norm(self.params['e'][h]+self.params['l'][r]-self.params['e'][t])

    def init_params(self):
        e = np.random.uniform(-6./self.k, 6./self.k, (self.n,self.k))
        l = normalize(np.random.uniform(-6./self.k, 6./self.k, (self.m,self.k)))
        params = {}
        params['e']=e
        params['l']=l
        return params

    def fit(self,S,nepochs=1000,validationset=None):
        self.params = self.init_params()

        for i in range(nepochs):
            np.random.shuffle(S)
            for batch in self.get_batches(S,self.b):
                self.params['e'] = normalize(self.params['e'])
                grad = self.evaluate_grad(batch)
                self.params['e'] -= self.lamb * grad['e']
                self.params['l'] -= self.lamb * grad['l']
            if not validationset == None: print (i,self.meanrank(validationset))

        return self

    def predict(self,h,r):
        q = self.params['e'][h] + self.params['l'][r]
        if self.d == 'l1':
            return np.abs(q-self.params['e']).sum(axis=1)
        elif self.d == 'l2':
            return np.linalg.norm(q-self.params['e'], axis=1)
```

Comment: これ [ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() というエラーが出る](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/52075/26370) と同様と思われます。エラーメッセージで示された行の判定処理や変数を見直してみてください。

Comment: 「公開されていたコード」というのは  [TransE "NIPS'13" を実装(と実験再現)した](http://yamaguchiyuto.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/02/25/080356) の物でしょうか？第三者が書いたコードを参照する場合には、必ず出典元を明記しましょう。 / 特に今回の場合、複数のファイルで構成されているようなので実行したファイルとエラーが出ているファイルが別のはずで、その辺りの情報も必要になってきます。

Comment: この辺の記事 [Pythonの配列の要素数が0かそれ以外かを判定する方法のパフォーマンス](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/56391/26370), [PythonでNone判定をしてNoneでなければその変数をif分の中で処理するには](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/47199/26370) があるので、まずは判定処理を`if validationset:`や`if validationset in not None:`とやって試してみるとか。

Comment: kunifさん，cubickさんコメントありがとうございます．自身でサイトを読んでみます．また，出典についてご指摘がありましたので，編集しました．ありがとうございました．